# embedded tomcat 7 behind iis 7.5 proxy ssl problems

Tags: tomcat, iis-7.5, arr

I'm using embedded tomcat 7 behind a iis 7.5 proxy server, with requests being forwarded to tomcat with arr.

Everything works fine unless iis is set to require ssl.

Then things like links that are generated dynamically in `.jsp` files on tomcat don't work right. **For example** if a link is supposed to point to `https://somewhere.com:443` it will be written as `http://somewhere.com:8080` (8080 is the port tomcat is running on).

The problem seems to come from when tomcat looks at itself to build out the url it sees correctly that it is running on `http://somewhere.com:8080`, but I need it to think otherwise.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this without using ssl between iis and tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to Tomcat not knowing the actual external `URL` of the application.
When the application redirects to a relative URL, the Servlet add the full absolute URL to Location (as required).

If you are using `HTTP` between `IIS` and Tomcat, Tomcat thinks you are using `HTTP` and generates `http://...` absolute `URL`.

The solution is not using `HTTP` (nor `HTTPS`) between `IIS` and Tomcat.
You should use `AJP13` protocol and the `Tomcat-ISAPI Redirector` on `IIS`.
[Here is the official Tomcat+IIS how to](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html).

Using Apache as proxy you could use HTTP for proxying, but you need configure Apache's `mod_proxy` and tell Tomcat it is behind a proxy.  [Here is a how to on that process](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html).